# second call to initmap() produce "google is not defined" error in console

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

In my application I am fetching lat and long from database and displaying markers on the Google map.
Initially I am fetching lat and long by default, and loading markers, which is working fine.

Now, after a form submit, I am taking the input values and fetching data from database and calling a JS function with the newly created array as parameter and calling the initmap().

Now, the crazy part is I have achieved what my goal is. My application is running perfectly fine, but in the JS console I can still see 
`Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined`

I would like to know if I am calling the inimap() wrong, or any suggestions are appreciated.

Here's my PHP and form code -

```
<?PHP
    $markingsArray = array();
    //Code to fetch and assign values to array $markingsArray
?>

<form action="" method="get">
    <table style="font:normal 100% 'century gothic', arial, sans-serif">
    <tr>
    <td>Year</td><td>:</td><td><select id="insYear" name="insYear">
    <option>2016</option>
    <option>2017</option>
    <option>2018</option>
    </select> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Club</td><td>:</td><td><select id="clubname" name="clubname">
      <option>BaseBall</option>
    <option>Football</option>
    <option>Others</option>
    </select> </td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="load" value="Load the club info" class="button button1"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</form>

<?PHP
    if(isset($_GET['load'])) {
        $clubInp = $_GET["clubname"];
        $yearInp = $_GET["insYear"];
        $clubyearRequestedData = array();
      //........
      //Here Code to fetch and fill this array $clubyearRequestedData
      //........

      echo "<script async type='text/javascript'>";
      echo"updateFilteredMarkers(".json_encode($clubyearRequestedData).");";
      echo"</script>";
?>
```

Here comes my Javascript code which is in the same page..

```
   <script type='text/javascript'>
    var markingsLocal = <?php echo json_encode($markingsArray); ?>;

    function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 14,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.697465, -89.613393),
        //disableDefaultUI: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
        fullscreenControl: false
    });

    callingThis();
    otherFunction1();
    otherFunction2();
    }

    function updateFilteredMarkers(clubyearRequestedData){
        markingsLocal = clubyearRequestedData;
        initMap();
    }

    function callingThis(){
        for (var i=0;i<markingsLocal.length;i++){
        //Using the array values to create markers on map.
    }
</script>
<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxxxxxxxMyAPIKeyxxxxxxxxxx&libraries=places&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you post the form, the page reloads.  In that case, you call `updateFilteredMarkers` before the API is loaded, generating the message you see, then when API loads, it runs `initMap` again, this time it works (because the API is loaded).  You don't need the call to `initMap` inside `updateFilteredMarkers` as it will be run after the API loads.

Comment: Hi, I need to call the three different functions which are called in the initMap() function, so I thought I can directly call initMap() reducing few lines of code to keep it clean.
I see what you mean, and I tried your suggestion, but it still shows the same error.